# Table doesn't carry header to new page mPDF

Tags: mpdf

#### I have this problem/would like to have this functionality

I have an issue similar to [#375](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/375) but rather, my tables function mostly as expected from the documentation. The only thing that I can't make sense of is that my table headers will start on one page, and then for a long table, or if it just extends past the end of the page, the table data will move to the next page, without it's table header.

#### These are mPDF and PHP versions I am using

mPDF 6.1.0. PHP 5.6.21

#### Below are some examples of the issue I'm having.

The second screenshot has a very long table that displays on the second page (which mPDF shrinks to fit all on the one page I believe).

[image: screenshot 14]
[image: screenshot 15]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, I just needed to keep looking through the documentation.

By applying the `page-break-inside: avoid` style to my table my problem was fixed.

I'm not totally sure if having the attribute `repeat_header='1'` on my table was also relevant, but that was what I had originally attempted to use to solve my problem.

Comment: In my experience, the page-break-inside shrinks the table to try and keep it in one page. This just made everything smaller, which wasn't desirable. But the repeat_header actually maintained the headers in the next page.